# conversion of progress bar to spinning wheel

Tags: android

i am using [this](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/) tutorial for progress which is working pretty well , i want to convert it to the spinning wheel is there any way to achive like this , 
[image]

```
should i have to go for 


   ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                            "Loading. Please wait...", true)
```

I have updated like this but its not working

```
public class Webview extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Adds Progrss bar Support
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.weblayout );

        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(  Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 

        // Get Web view
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.MyWebview ); //This is the id you gave 
                                                             //to the WebView in the main.xml
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);         //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this 
                                                             //if ROM supports Multi-Touch      
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM

        // Load URL
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.firstdroid.com/advertisement.htm");


        // Sets the Chrome Client, and defines the onProgressChanged
        // This makes the Progress bar be updated.
        final Activity MyActivity = this;
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        {


            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

            // Return the app name after finish loading
            if(progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
          }
        });



    }//End of Method onCreate
}
```

Comment: one can solve this problem by this http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2010/05/04/android-webview-and-the-indeterminant-progress-solution/

Comment: What is your MyActivity.setProgress() method? I think you call it with wrong parameters, because progress is integer number in 0-100 range. Also I think that use of static methods for such purpose is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spinning wheel (known as the `STYLE_SPINNER`) is the default implementation of a `ProgressDialog` when instantiated, therefore the code you have written should work fine.

To usually set the style of the ProgressDialog, you can call the `setProgressStyle` method on the `ProgressDialog` you create before calling the `show` method. Like so:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern , please can you point it out to which line in the code i have to replace the above line . once again thanks

Comment: Please give a look to updated question , i have tried to put but its not working , please guide me about it